# Doit-on remplacer « les » par « leur » dans la phrase « [...] qui vont les rapprocher » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, compléments

J’ai tendance à le croire, parce que « leur » est un complément indirect, « les » un complément direct, et que le verbe « rapprocher » demande un complément indirect.

En écrivant cette question, j’ai senti que la différence était peut-être entre la notion de « rapprocher à » et celle de simplement se rapprocher, c’est-à-dire :

- « Leila et Huston rapprochent par lettres » → « Les lettres, qui vont les rapprocher »

Est-ce logique ?

Comment: Votre question est très difficile à comprendre. Peut-être auriez-vous plus de facilités à la formuler en anglais?

Comment: J'ai tenté de traduire la question en français standard. Je n'ai pas tout compris, mais peut-être quelqu'un saurait-il prendre le relais.

Comment: Sorry everybody, I thought the writting was compreensive :/
I think that the adaption was done in the best way. Thank you and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @Laure I wrote this in order to mean ``I have that thought`` and yet I believe that it isn`t an anglophone structure I am used to saying it in Brazilian Portuguese....

Comment: @YassinRany No need to apologize, we're here to help. I particularly appreciate when OPs make the effort to write their questions in French, shows they are motivated. And there's always s.o. to help correct the mistakes, which will help them improve their French. I don't speak Brazilian but I expect it's close to the Spanish *soy pensando* ?

Comment: @Laure thank you, your words means a lot for me :) There is a long time that I am without any experience with Spanish, but I would say estoy pensando to mean I am thinking, to translate what I wanted to mean, I would say yo pienso así... Please don`t trust in my Spanish haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(French answer)*

En bref, il existe plusieurs sens de « rapprocher », dont tous n'exigent pas la même syntaxe.

Les deux que vous semblez comparer sont les suivants :

1. « rapprocher » Réduire les distances entre deux choses (*fig.*: réunir deux personnnes).

   > La correspondance rapproche Leila et Houston.
2. « se rapprocher de » Devenir plus proche de (*fig.*: se réunir avec une personne).

   > Houston se rapproche de Leila par correspondance. Ils se rapprochent l'un de l'autre par correspondance.

Notez que le premier sens prend un *complément d'objet direct*. C'est ce complément qui sera remplacé par *les* dans une phrase comme celle-ci :

> La correpondance **les** rapproche (Leila et Houston).

Mais le deuxième sens ne prend pas *leur*. Pourquoi ? Parce qu'on ne dit pas « se rapprocher *à* », mais « se rapprocher *de* ». Le pronom *leur* remplace « *à* eux, *à* elles, *à* deux personnes ou objets ».

Le pronom qui convient à « *de* quelqu'un(e), *de* quelque chose » est *en* :

> Houston s'**en** rapproche (de Leila).

Cela dit, @StéphaneGimenez dit ci-dessous que *en* ne peut pas faire référence à *l'un de l'autre* ; on y entendrait plutôt que les deux personnes se rapprochent à une troisième chose. Donc on l'écrira tout simplement sans pronom :

> Ils se rapprochent (l'un de l'autre).

Donc le pronom sera *les* pour le premier sens, et *en*, ou rien, pour le deuxième.

---

*(English answer)*

In short, there are several meanings of « rapprocher », and not all of them involve the same syntax.

The two you seem to be comparing are these:

1. « rapprocher » Reduce the distance between two things (*fig.* reunite two people).

   > La correspondance rapproche Leila et Houston.
   >
   > <sub>The correspondence brings Leila and Houston closer together.</sub>
2. « se rapprocher de » Get closer to (*fig.* reunite with a person).

   > Houston se rapproche de Leila par correspondance. Ils se rapprochent l'un de l'autre par correspondance.
   >
   > <sub>Houston becomes closer to Leila through correspondence. They become closer to each other through correspondence.</sub>

Note that the first meaning takes a *direct object*. It's that direct object that will be replaced by *les* in a sentence like this one:

> La correspondance **les** rapproche (Leila et Houston).
>
> <sub>The correspondence brings **them** together (Leila and Houston).</sub>

But the second meaning doesn't take *leur*. Why? Because we don't say "se rapprocher *à*", but "se rapprocher *de*". The pronoun *leur* replaces "*à* eux, *à* elles, *à* deux personnes ou objets".

The pronoun that matches "*de* quelqu'un(e), *de* quelque chose" is *en* :

> Houston s'**en** rapproche (de Leila).
>
> <sub>Houston becomes closer to her (to Leila).</sub>

However, @StéphaneGimenez states below that *en* can't refer to *l'un de l'autre*; instead, it would mean they both approach a third thing. So you can simply write it without a pronoun:

> Ils se rapprochent (l'un de l'autre).
>
> They become closer (to each other).

So the pronoun will be *les* for the first meaning, and *en* or nothing for the second.

Comment: P.S. Aux locuteurs natifs et aux rédacteurs plus expérimentés : Je ne suis pas *tout à fait* certain de ce que ces phrases soient naturelles ; corrigez-moi sans hésitation si besoin !

Comment: Pour le 2) je dirais plus facilement *par lettres.* Ceci dit je préférerais parler de « correspondance » que de « lettres ». Autres possibilité à envisager éventuellement : *Ce sont les lettres /c'est le courrier qui rapproche Houston et Leila (qui les rapproche/nt*). Nice explanation.

Comment: @Laure Merci ; j'ai incorporé « correspondance ».

Comment: *Ils s'en rapprochent* cannot mean « ils se rapprochent l'un de l'autre ». Here *en* would refer to a third entity. In particular « ils s'en rapprochent l'un de l'autre » is not correct.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez How, if at all, would you pronominalize *Ils se rapprochent l'un de l'autre* "They approach each other"? And could the phrasing with *en* alone really never mean *l'un de l'autre*, or is it just very likely to be misunderstood as a third party?

Comment: It's already pronominalized two times, with “se” and “l'un de l'autre” (the latter is only needed if disambiguation is necessary). The “en” pronoun is not reflexive (nor reciprocal) and can only point to an entity that is not one of the subjects.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Merci, incorporé (correctement je crois, mais vous pourriez vérifier si besoin !).

Answer (score 1):

In short:  no.  The correct phrase is "..qui vont les rapprocher".  If you were in a case-using language, 'leur' would be for the datif, while the complement d'objet, direct ou indirect, is the accusatif. ".. qui vont leur faciliter un rapprochement" for instance would be a datif-using formulation.

Comment: makes mores sense in a case analysis! Merci ))

Answer (score 0):

La bonne locution en français est « Leila et Huston se rapprochent par lettres interposées » → « Les lettres, qui vont les rapprocher » aucune raison d'y mettre "leur" avant rapprocher.

Eventuellement « Leurs lettres, qui vont les rapprocher »